# getMyLocation can't immediately get location when calling from new activity onCreate

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm trying to create an activity, upon starting it, I'll have a map that immediately access my current location in the map and move towards it.

So I call the below during the onCreate()...

```
public void moveToCurrentLocation()
{
    if ( !mLM.isProviderEnabled( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER ) ) {
        buildAlertMessageNoGps();
    }
    else
    {
        Location myloc = mMap.getMyLocation();
        //if (myloc == null ) myloc = mLM.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if (myloc != null) {
            LatLng position = new LatLng(myloc.getLatitude(), myloc.getLongitude());
            moveToLocation(position);
            return;
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Sorry no location information obtained yet. Try click again on 'current location button' on the map", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    moveToLocation(SINGAPORE, false, 9);

}
```

What happen is, getMyLocation always return Null initially, and after awhile only, it will be able to get the location. The workaround I use is getLastKnownLocation from LocationManager to solve the problem. However, the LastKnownLocation might not be the current location.

So how could I solve the problem to ensure getMyLocation will get the data immediately upon starting of the activity? Thanks.

Comment: move the call to onStart().

Answer (score 0):

please do not use GpsTracker it has a lot of bugs.
try this solution :

http://gabesechansoftware.com/location-tracking/

i replace my gps tracker with it and it work perfectly.

Comment: Thanks Maor. Checked googlemap, seemingly the behaviour is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Gps will take some time to get locked and fetch Location. Around 20-30sec. And at that time it need to see the sky.

 So use GooglePlay Service and fetch the last known location and fetch the location so that yo can use it in future.